# Comparing colour profiles in opencv

Tags: opencv

I have different images with various colours distributed in a circle.[image]

How can I compare these colour profiles between different images?

Currently I'm using the following algorithm:

1. "Draw" a circle with radius 50% of the inner circle.
2. Pick the RGB value of the pixel on the circumference of the circle.
3. Store this RGB value in a vector.
4. Compare RGB values from different images.

But this a brute force method of comparing, which I do not intend.

**EDITED**

I guess I have not explained the problem correctly. I have objects with yellow inside red circles (or rather, 2 concentric circles with different colours). The inner circle has gradual and minor colour changes (as shown in image) which is the distinguishing factor. I need to recognize the objects based on these colour changes. The amount of red, green, blue, etc in the image maybe same, what differs is their distribution. How can I represent this colour change?

**EDIT 2**
[image]
[image]

With the algorithm I have mentioned, I have represented the RGB pixels along the circumference of 2 different objects. These 2 images show the "placement" of colours differ, but the amount and the pattern is almost same.

Comment: maybe you need to explain, what you want to do with the 'color profiles'

Comment: @berak : these are different objects (for simplicity I have drawn these in Gimp, but they will be actual images), with colour distribution at the center. I need to compare the colour distribution for recognizing the objects

Answer (score 1):

Use [**histogram comparison**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html) for measuring the similitude of your *color profiles*.

For each image, calculate its color Histogram. Then, cross-compare your images using their histogram distances.

Comment: But the histogram comparison will give just the number of pixels in each color range. It won't say much about how the colour varies.

Comment: You should try it. The representational power of color histograms can be way bigger than you think. Plus, it is cheap and easy to implement (not only in C++ OpenCV, but in other languages and frameworks).

Comment: Sure I will check it and get back.

Comment: hist compare seems to work fine. But I need to test few more samples before I accept the answer. Also, can there be a 2nd line of comparison algorithm apart from histogram, just to be sure?

Comment: I've just read your edit. Two things: IF the only part which varies across your images is the inner yellow circle, make sure you use a mask excluding the outter circle when calculating the histogram (for efficiency!). Also if it is true that `The amount of red, green, blue, etc in the image maybe same`, then of course histogram comparison can be not enough. And yes, you can add extra stages for comparison: e.g. if your images have characteristic (unique) shapes, you can use other approaches like Sum of Squared Differences (SSD), which can be easily implemented in OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to guess your actual goal from your input image. You should also provide an example of desired output to make things clearer.

Assuming that the image with the big red ring and some colors inside is similar to one of your actual images, you may want to try:

- *circle detection* (using [Hough transform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghcircles)) to segment your image into gross areas. This would provide you at least with the red ring opposed to the inner part;
- *color clustering*. Assuming you know a priori how many different colors you have, you can try the simple [K-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) algorithm (unfortunately, it does not seem to be readily accessible in OpenCV API). If you don't have a prior on the number of classes, you can try OpenCV's [FLANN](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/flann/doc/flann.html) hierarchical clustering and set a color distance threshold on the maximum size ( = color spread) of the colors to detect. Juste use the RGB colors as feature vectors.